# match operation for array size gt 0 does not work in aggregation MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have an mongo collection called Book.

```
{
    "_id" : "00000000",
    "name" : "Book1",
    "similarBooks" : [],
    "genre" : ""
}
```

similarBooks is an array in the Book collection which contains other books which are similar to Book1.

I want to find all the books which are having similar books to it. which means i need to match similarBooks array size gt 0 in my aggregation.

I was using the aggregation-

```
db.Book.aggregate([{
            "$match": {
                "similarBooks": {
                    "$gt": {
                        "$size": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

But it is not working. 
There is another option of using $expr in the match condition,

```
db.Book.aggregate([{ {
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $gt: [{
                            $size: "$similarBooks"
                        }, 0]
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

but we can not use $expr while creating the partial index, so I can not use the second option using $expr in my aggregation. Is there any other way I can run the aggregation to find the array size gt 0.

I am using MongoDB shell version v4.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongo's [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) combined with [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/).

```
db.Book.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": {
                "similarBooks.0": {"$exists": true}
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: I want to avoid arrays with empty values ([]). {"$exists": true} will not do that

Comment: it will, did you even try?

Comment: I was wrong, the aggregation works. Thank you for that, but how can I create an partial index with this match condition. I tried db.Book.createIndex({
      similarBooks: 1
  }, {
      partialFilterExpression: {
          "similarBooks.0": {
              "$exists": true
          }
      }
  })
and my aggregation did not use the partial index